# Javascript, AJAX, Extend PHP Session Timeout, Bank Timeout

Tags: javascript

Greetings,

I have the following JS code:

```
var reloadTimer = function (options) {
  var seconds = options.seconds || 0,
      logoutURL = options.logoutURL,
      message = options.message;

  this.start = function () {
    setTimeout(function (){
      if ( confirm(message) ) {
        // RESET TIMER HERE
        $.get("renewSession.php"); 

      } else {
        window.location.href = logoutURL;
      }
    }, seconds * 1000);
  }

  return this;
};
```

And I would like to have the timer reset where I have the comment for RESET TIMER HERE. I have tried a few different things to no avail. Also the code calling this block is the following:

```
var timer = reloadTimer({  seconds:20, logoutURL: 'logout.php',
                     message:'Do you want to stay logged in?'});
timer.start();
```

The code may look familiar as I found it on SO :-)

Thanks!

Comment: Take this as a lesson; not all code you find on SO is quality code. This piece here is actually quite bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to use the `new` operator in `var timer = new reloadTimer`, and also reloadTimer should be capitalized into ReloadTimer to signify that it needs to be used with `new`.

The reason why you need `new` is because the function references `this` and when used without `new` this will be the global scope instead of the instance it self.

To reset a timer you just call window.clearTimeout with the timers reference as the parameter

```
var timer = window.setTimeout(....
...
window.clearTimeout(timer);
```

**UPDATE**

By RESET do you actally mean to restart the timer?

If so, just use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`

**UPDATE 2**

And here is a slightly better approach (if you still want to use such a class to encapsulate something so trivial)

```
var ReloadTimer = function(options){
    var seconds = options.seconds || 0, logoutURL = options.logoutURL, message = options.message;
    var timer;
    return {
        start: function(){
            timer = setInterval(function(){
                if (confirm(message)) {
                    $.get("renewSession.php");
                }
                else {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    window.location.href = logoutURL;
                }
            }, seconds * 1000);
        }
    };
};
var myTimer = new ReloadTimer({
    seconds: 20,
    logoutURL: 'logout.php',
    message: 'Do you want to stay logged in?'
});
myTimer.start();
```

Comment: You rock Sean! I plugged in your changes and it works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: Follow up question, how can I get the confirm window to automatically disappear after 5 seconds and return false? Thanks!

Comment: You cannot when using the built-in `confirm` method. You will have to resort to some UI library providing a similar feature.

Answer (score 0):

You could execute the function again with the same parameters?